# Type cast Postgresql function arguments called in Python

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I'm calling a postgresql function from within Python using psycopg2.

```
    cur.callproc('model_filter', [
    f_filename,
    f_age_min,
    f_age_max,
    f_height,
    f_ethnicity1_old,
    f_ethnicity2_old,
    f_ethnicity3_old,
    f_filename_old,
    f_gender,
    f_ethnicity1,
    f_ethnicity2,
    f_ethnicity3,
    f_skullexcl,
    f_eyesexcl,
    f_noseexcl,
    f_mouthexcl,
    f_earsexcl,
    f_source,
    f_client,
    f_textures,
    f_skintone
    ])
```

This gives me an error:

*psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function model_filter(unknown, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, text[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], integer[], text[], text[]) does not exist*

As you can see it is not recognizing the string parameters such as f_filename as the text type in Postgresql, instead it says the type is unknown.

How can I either force the python strings to be recognized as text or explicitly type cast these string variables as text?

Below is my postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION model_filter(
f_filename text,
f_age_min integer,
f_age_max integer,
f_height text,
f_ethnicity1_old text,
f_ethnicity2_old text,
f_ethnicity3_old text,
f_filename_old text,
f_gender integer[],
f_ethnicity1 integer[],
f_ethnicity2 integer[],
f_ethnicity3 integer[],
f_skullexcl integer[],
f_eyesexcl integer[],
f_noseexcl integer[],
f_mouthexcl integer[],
f_earsexcl integer[],
f_source integer[],
f_client integer[],
f_textures text[],
f_skintone text[]
)
RETURNS TABLE (
id integer,
filename text,
filepath text,
age integer,
gender integer,
ethnicity1 integer,
ethnicity2 integer,
ethnicity3 integer,
skullexcl integer,
eyesexcl integer,
noseexcl integer,
mouthexcl integer,
earsexcl integer,
wrapped integer,
"source" integer,
client integer,
"character" text,
indexphoto text,
height text,
l_ethnicity1 text,
l_ethnicity2 text,
l_ethnicity3 text,
l_filename text,
l_filepath text,
textures text,
skintone text
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * from models
      WHERE models.filename LIKE f_filename AND models.age BETWEEN f_age_min AND f_age_max AND models.height LIKE f_height
        AND COALESCE(models.l_ethnicity1,'') LIKE f_ethnicity1_old AND COALESCE(models.l_ethnicity2,'') LIKE f_ethnicity2_old
        AND COALESCE(models.l_ethnicity3,'') LIKE f_ethnicity3_old AND models.l_filename LIKE f_filename_old
        AND models.gender = ANY(f_gender) AND models.ethnicity1 = ANY(f_ethnicity1) AND models.ethnicity2 = ANY(f_ethnicity2)
        AND models.ethnicity3 = ANY(f_ethnicity3) AND models.skullexcl = ANY(f_skullexcl) AND models.eyesexcl = ANY(f_eyesexcl)
        AND models.noseexcl = ANY(f_noseexcl) AND models.mouthexcl = ANY(f_mouthexcl) AND models.earsexcl = ANY(f_earsexcl)
        AND models.source = ANY(f_source) AND models.client = ANY(f_client)
        AND models.textures = ANY(f_textures) AND models.skintone = ANY(f_skintone)
        ORDER BY models.ID;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is this, `'%'+f_filename+'%'` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited my question to hopefully be more clear. I also removed the '%' signs from the variables to avoid confusion as that's not really relevant (f_filename is a string search field input so the percentage signs on either end means that the search will return any string with f_filename contained within it)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What is the signature for `model_filter` when you look at in the database? How are `f_filename` and the other text variables defined?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver f_filename is simply any string 'test' for example. I have updated my question with the postgresql function

Comment: The issue seems to be with `f_gender`. In the function it is defined as `integer[]` . In the `callproc` it is being supplied as `text[]`.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that... thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked. FYI, `callproc` does not exist in the next version of `psycopg`: `psycopg3` per [psycopg3 differences](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html) so you should probably get used to using `execute('select from some_func()')`. Also despite the name `callproc()` does not work with `Procedure`s and you will have to use `execute()` for them.